# Inspecting or turning off Numpy/SciPy Parallelization

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, scipy, scikit-learn

I am running some K-Means clustering from the sklearn package.

Although I am setting the parameter `n_jobs = 1` as indicated in the sklearn documentation, and  although a single process is running, that process will apparently consume all the CPUs on my machine. That is, in `top`, I can see the python job is using, say 400% on a 4 core machine.

To be clear, if I set `n_jobs = 2`, say, then I get two python instances running, but each one uses 200% CPU, again consuming all 4 of my machine's cores.

I believe the issue may be parallelization at the level of NumPy/SciPy.

Is there a way to verify my assumption? Is there a way to turn off any parallelization in NumPy/SciPy, for example?

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, which you can confirm by following the code. The parallelization is in the BLAS that numpy was build with. I don't think you can turn it of (though I am not 100% sure).

Comment: Wouldn't this be an issue for people who need to run this code on shared resources? It's the issue I am running into. Without customization of this parallelization, I'd have to request the max amount of CPUs on each machine in the queueing system.

Comment: Shouldn't your scheduling system take care of that?

Comment: I mean I can request all CPUs per machine but this is unnecessary when I'd be happy to just use one core and get my jobs running and out of queue quicker.

Comment: Also the parallization can have some large overhead and it makes no sense if you are already doing higher level parallization without overhead, e.g. by splitting the data into separate partitions or generally running separate jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed BLAS, or in my case OpenBLAS, was performing the parallelization.

The solution was to set the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to `1`.

Then all is right with the world.